# PHP Google+ Plaform server side user verification and get access token

Tags: php, android, server-side, google-plus

I'm using the Google+ Platform on my android app with PlusClient and all that good stuff.

When the user signs in he can interact with my PHP server to get some content, but on every request i want to verify if the user is who he says he is.

For that purpose, on every PHP request i ask for the id and access token so that i can call "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=$accessToken" and check if the id is the same as on the access token.

Is this a valid server-side user auth verification method? If not, what is the best approach?

My other question is how do i get the access token when i connect with the PlusClient to send to the PHP server? Do i have to call the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES, you'll need to use GoogleAuthUtil.getToken
That's actually what the PhotoHunt Android sample app do.
You just have to copy/paste the source code from https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/android#authenticating_with_photohunt

```
sAccessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(ctx, account, "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The answer is correct regarding the accesstoken, and what about the method i'm using to verify the identity of the user? When i get the accesstoken from the gettoken every call i make to the server further on i send that token in the query string (e.g: http://www.myserver/buyItem.php?userID=123&accessToken=dfwjhdfhsdhfj), and on the php server i just make a HTTP request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=$AccessTokenSentFromTheUser and check if the google plus id of the user that has the id $userID on my DB is equal to the google plus id on the token.